# Present query data in different format - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have the query that presents results in the following way:

```
{"declined": [{"2018-01-16": 1}], "negative": [{"2018-01-16": 1}], "positive": [{"2018-01-16": 2}]}
```

query looks like this:

```
select 
jsonb_build_object('positive', 
  json_agg(jsonb_build_object(date, positive)) FILTER (WHERE positive <> 0)
) ||
jsonb_build_object('negative',
  json_agg( jsonb_build_object(date, negative)) FILTER (WHERE negative <> 0)
) ||
jsonb_build_object('declined', 
  json_agg(jsonb_build_object(date, declined)) FILTER (WHERE declined <> 0)
)
from (
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at) as date,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium'))) AS positive,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('low'))) AS negative,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (coalesce(raw#>>'{survey,denied}','f') = 'true')) AS declined
  FROM survey_results
  GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at)
) as t1;
```

I'm trying to refactor that query to return me json that looks like this:

```
{"2018-01-16": {"positive": 2, "declined": "1", "negative": 1}}
```

How can I do that? Here is sql fiddle that You can experiment with:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9705/8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9705/54/0 ?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing smth - I just `jsonb_build_object` on `jsonb_build_object`:

```
select 
jsonb_build_object(date,jsonb_build_object('positive',positive,'negative',negative,'declined',declined))
from (
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at) as date,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium'))) AS positive,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('low'))) AS negative,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (coalesce(raw#>>'{survey,denied}','f') = 'true')) AS declined
  FROM survey_results
  GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at)
) t1
```

and result:

`{"2018-01-16": {"declined": 1, "negative": 1, "positive": 2}}`